# Convert Decimal into Binary using Recursion in R

Tags: r

This function works flawlessly but it is so confusing, can someone explain this code to me, how does it work? I understand the concept of recursion but the cat(n %% 2) part does not make sense to me
Somehow, I also can not save the result.

```
convert_to_binary <- function(n) {
if(n > 1) {
convert_to_binary(as.integer(n/2))
}
cat(n %% 2)
}
```

Comment: If the value of 'n' is greater than 1, divide by 2 and convert to integer so that all the floating points are removed recursively and then take the modulus of n and print in each step

Answer (score 0):

Here is a two part answer to your two part question.

**First, how does the function work?**

Lets use an example. Consider `convert_to_binary(9).`

*Step 1*: The function checks to see if `n=9` is greater than one. It is, and so the function performs *itself* on the integer part of `9/2`, namely `4`.

*Step 2*:The function checks to see if `n=4` is greater than one. It is, and so the function performs *itself* on the integer part of `4/2`, namely `2`.

*Step 3*:The function checks to see if `n=2` is greater than one. It is, and so the function performs *itself* on the integer part of `2/2`, namely `1`.

*Step 4*:The function checks to see if `n=1` is greater than one. It is *not*, and so the function performs its final step (the `cat(n %% 2)` part) with `n=1`.

*Step 5*: `n %% 2` is R for n (mod 2) and so since 1 (mod 2) is 1, `cat` collects `1` for final output.

*Step 6* Now, since `convert_to_binary(1)` is finished, we move on to the end phase of `convert_to_binary(2)`. Thus, since 2 (mod 2) is 0, `cat` collects `0` for final output, giving us `10` for our final output (which is still being built).

*Step 7* Now, since `convert_to_binary(2)` is finished, we move on to the end phase of `convert_to_binary(4)`. Thus, since 4 (mod 2) is 0, `cat` collects `0` for final output, giving us `100` for our final output (which is still being built).

*Step 8* Now, since `convert_to_binary(4)` is finished, we move on to the end phase of `convert_to_binary(9)`. Thus, since 9 (mod 2) is 1, `cat` collects `1` for final output, giving us `1001` for our final output. Since `cat` is now finished collecting output, this is printed to your console.

`cat` does not return a value, which is why you are unable to save any of these values. This leads us to part two of the answer.

**Second, how can we save the value?**

This is a modified form of your function, using the exact same process. However, this function actually returns the binary form of the input integer. Hope this has helped!

```
convert_to_binary <- function(n) {
  bin <- ''
  if(n > 1) {
    bin <- convert_to_binary(as.integer(n/2))
  }
  bin <- paste0(bin, n %% 2)
  return(as.numeric(bin))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detail comment. Your function makes much more sense to me than one in my question, especially this part:  
bin <- paste0(bin, n %% 2)

My question is why and how does cat() work?
Like in step 6, n = 2, cat(n%%2) is 0, how can it collect previous value 1 and put out 10?

Comment: @viet_datar You're welcome! ```cat()``` is similar to print. However, if multiple calls of ```cat()``` are executed with a single command, ```cat()``` prints ALL of those calls out at the same time (the end), as a single string. Try this example to see the difference between print and cat: ```test_cat <- function(n){
  if(n > 1){
    print(n)
    test_cat(n-1)
  }
  cat(n)
}

test_cat(10)```